# "Close" button for Java app in OS X on right side

Tags: java, macos

I'm migrating a Java application from Windows to Mac OS X. I've wrapped it in an application bundle, and everything works perfectly, except the window decoration. While running the app in Eclipse the buttons are shown on the left side (as expected from a OS X app), but they are displayed on the right side when the application bundle is executed.
Is there anything that can/should be configured in the application bundle so that it retains the Mac-style decoration?

Comment: Can you please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: @s.d I created a demonstration app, but the problem does not happen. I'll have to investigate. Any other ideas?